# Are multi-sig M-of-N transactions with N > 3 supported?

Tags: multi-signature

[BIP 11](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0011.mediawiki) makes M-of-N multi-sig transactions standard --- for N <= 3. What is the current support among miners for the multi-sig transactions with N > 3? (say 3-of-6). Also, BIP 11 states:

> The current Satoshi bitcoin client does not relay or mine transactions with scriptSigs larger than 200 bytes; to accomodate 3-signature transactions, this will be increased to 500 bytes.

Does this still hold, and if yes, does this limit come into play for N > 3 or M > 3? What other obstacles are in the way of standardizing M-of-N for meaningful N?

Comment: I suspect  the biggest obstacle is the fact that it will create a fork in the chain due to the fact new nodes can create seemingly invalid transactions for old nodes.

Comment: Cross post from: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=508256.msg5618510#msg5618510

Comment: What % of miners will mine these transactions where N > 3?

Answer (score 1):

Standard multisig outputs have max 3 keys, but it is possible to add up to 16 keys.

This limit is probably a result of the hard limit of output script size.

EDIT: source: I don't remember where I found this information. (I implemented it in [Dartcoin](https://github.com/dartcoin/dartcoin-lib) and put that in the documentation.) As an alternative source, check out Mike Hearn's BitcoinJ implementation [here](https://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/source/browse/core/src/main/java/com/google/bitcoin/script/ScriptBuilder.java#132).

Comment: If you use PS2H method there's no limit. Check Pieter's comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23893/what-are-the-limits-of-m-and-n-in-m-of-n-multisig-addresses#comment28691_23915